# Ideal $\langle x - 1 \rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^n - 1\rangle \equiv \mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^{n - 1} + \ldots + x + 1 \rangle $?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, ideals

Consider that we have the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^n - 1\rangle$. We define an ideal $\langle x - 1 \rangle$ on this ring. I read somewhere that it is equivalent to the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^{n - 1} + x^{n - 2} + \ldots + x + 1 \rangle$. How do we prove that it is so?
Moreover, similarly how do we prove that the ideal $\langle x^{n - 1} + x^{n - 2} + \ldots + x + 1 \rangle$ of quotient ring $R$ is equivalent to the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/ \langle x - 1 \rangle$?

If this statement is incomplete, then what needs to be added to it so that this equivalence holds?

Comment: **Hint:** $$x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\ldots +x+1)$$

Comment: @TobErnack, the problem is actually saying that the **ideal** $\langle x-1\rangle$ in $\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x^n-1\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\ldots +x+1\rangle$.

Comment: That is also doubtful, because there might not be a multiplicative identity, so it wouldn't be isomorphic to a ring with identity. For example if $n = 3$, is there an $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $f(x)(x - 1) + \langle x^3 - 1 \rangle$ acts as the identity element? If yes, then in particular it should fix the generator element $(x - 1) + \langle x^3 - 1 \rangle$. Thus $f(x)(x - 1)^2 - (x - 1) \in \langle x^3 - 1 \rangle$ and hence $f(x)(x - 1) - 1 = h(x)(x^2 + x + 1)$ for some $h(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Substituting $x = 1$ gives $3h(1) = -1$ which is impossible over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I would expect the correct statement to be: the ideal $\langle x - 1 \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x] / \langle x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + \cdots + x + 1 \rangle$ *as an $R$-module* (or less informatively, they are isomorphic as abelian groups).

Comment: Definitely, equivalent here needs to mean "isomorphic as $R$-modules."